# Managing nginx vhost files permissions in docker mounted volume

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, vhosts

I created a nginx docker container and mounted its document root (/srv/www) in the host (at the same location).

I also created an user and a group both in host and in the container with the same uid\gid.

My intentition was to create a directory in HOST /srv/www (say, /srv/www/mydir) owned by the user, but every time I try to chown, the ownership remains to root:root with a 777 permission.

This, in my view, creates a big security issue.

I would like to be able to create many virtual host, with different roots directories under /srv/www owned by different users but managed by the same nginx container.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was due to the fact that I was working inside a vm created with vagrant.